# Probability problem about a class students

Tags: probability

In a class, 80% of students are male and 70% of students are studying engineering. Among students, 60% of students are male and studying engineering. What percentage of students are female and are not studying engineering?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(M)=.8,\ P(E)=.7,\ P(M\cap E)=.6$.  General formula $P(M\cup E)=P(M)+P(E)-P(M\cap E)=.9$.  The answer you are looking for is $P(M'\cap E')=1-P(M\cup E)=.1$.